# program terminates unexpectedly after the introduction of catch block

Tags: c++, exception

I have a piece of code that runs normally, but it breaks when I add exception handling. I am a beginner and here's the code

This code works (for brevity's sake include guards are not shown):

In plane.h:

```
#include "vector.h" //which, like point.h, inherits from orderedpair.h
class Plane {
    public:
        Plane(const std::string &label);
        Plane(const Plane &);
        virtual ~Plane();

        void insert(const OrderedPair &);
        void label(const std::string & label);
        std::string label() const {return _label;}

    protected:
        std::string _label;
        bool operator==(const Plane &rhs) const {return label() == rhs.label();}
        bool operator<(const Plane & rhs) const {return label() < rhs.label();}
};
```

In plane.cpp

```
#include <set>
Plane::Plane(const std::string &label) : _label(label) {
     getUniverse().insert(this);
}

/*GLOBAL OBJECTS*/

extern std::set<Plane *>& getUniverse() {
    static std::set<Plane *>universe;
    return universe;
}

extern Plane& getDefaultPlane() {
    static Plane Default("Default");
    return Default;
}

void printworld() {
    for (auto i : getUniverse())
        std::cout << (*getUniverse().find(i))->label() << std::endl;
}
```

and in main:

```
//MinGW32 4.9 Code::Blocks 16.01 Windows Vista(!!) 64bit -std=C++11
#include <iostream>
#include "vector.h" //includes point.h which includes orderedpair.h
#include "plane.h"

using namespace std;

namespace {
    struct Initializer {;
        Initializer();
    };
}

int main() {

static Initializer init;
Point A("A", 1, 1);

Plane P("P");
Plane duplicate("Default");

printworld();
return 0;
}

Initializer::Initializer()
{
   // Trigger construction of the default Plane
   getDefaultPlane();
}
```

Then I include exception in plane.h and add the following at the top:

```
class E : public std::exception {
    const char *msg = nullptr;
public:
    E(const char *m) throw() : msg(m) {}
    const char *what() const throw() {return msg;}
};
const E DuplicateObj("Object already exists!\n");
```

It compiles and runs, without a problem.
Then I change the constructor of the Plane in this way (to make sure the label has not been used before):

```
Plane::Plane(const std::string &label) : _label(label) {
     for (auto i : getUniverse()) {
           if ((*getUniverse().find(i))->label() == _label) throw DuplicateObj;
     }
    getUniverse().insert(this);
}
```

and comment out the instantiation of duplicate plane in main (to avoid triggering the throw). It compiles and runs, no problem.

then I wrap the object instantiation lines in a try/catch block in main:

```
try {
    Point A("A", 1, 1);
    Plane P("P");
    //Plane duplicate("Default");
}
catch (const E& e) {
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
}
catch (const exception &e) {
    cerr << e.what() << endl;
}
```

It compiles but crashes with the following result:

```
Process returned -1073741819 (0xC0000005)   execution time : 9.537 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Comment: You don't need a private default constructor. As you supply another constructor, the default one will be suppressed.

Comment: I don't see the code where you throw the exception.

Comment: Ideally, post something complete and compilable.

Comment: Is the message really a static duration const char array?

Comment: The throw is in the commented-out part of the Plane constructor. The program  crashes even without a throw, but only when there is a try/catch block. @MartinBonner

Comment: what about changing `catch (exception &e)` with `catch (const exception &e)` ?

Comment: Can you show us a [mcve] please.  Remove all the commented out code.  Include all the code that is required to cause failure, and tell us what the crash message is.

Comment: Adding const didn't change this behavior, but thanks for pointing out @max66

Comment: (1) there is a bad `;` in `main.cpp` (`struct Initializer {;`); (2) would you please add `vector.h` and `orderpair.h`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't a problem of exceptions.

It's a problem of pointer and scope.

If I'm not wrong.

Your Plane constructor insert (`getUniverse().insert(this);`) the `this` pointer in a static global set (`static std::set<Plane *>universe;` in `getUniverse()`).

Then, you use that global set in the last instruction of `main()` (`printworld()`).

Before the introduction of the `try`/`catch` blocks, the scope of the `Plane P("P");` object is the full `main()` function; so the pointer to `P` is a valid pointer when you call `printworld`.

But when you write

```
try {
    Plane P("P");
    // end of P scope
 }

// P is out of scope; the pointer to P, in universe, is invalid

printworld(); // use of a invalid pointer to P
```

the scope of `P` is only the `try` block; so, when you call `printworld()` out of `try` block, `universe` contain a pointer to a destroied object.

Crash!

p.s.: sorry for my bad english.

Comment: This is precisely the problem! I had figured out that the problem is with the scope, but I couldn't figure out what it is exactly. You hit the nail on the head! Thanks a lot! Is there a way to avoid this other than declaring P off the heap? @max66

Comment: I don't know if there are other ways. Just keep in mind that `universe` uses pointers, so you have to make sure those pointers are valid. In this case, you can use `new`/`delete` or you can use `printworld` inside the `try` block